# How to compare arrays in GROQ

Tags: subquery, sanity, groq, array-comparison

I have a blog with sanity CMS and I want to request related posts depending on corresponding tags from the current post which means I have to compare two arrays of tags.

My tags are described in post schema this way:

```js
{
  name: 'tags',
  title: 'Tags',
  type: 'array',
  of: [{type: 'string'}],
  options: {
    layout: 'tags'
  }
},
```

I went with the following GROQ query which is a good start I guess but obviously it doesn't work:

```js
*[_type == "post" && slug.current == $slug][0] {
  title,
  tags,
  "sameTags": *[_type == "post" && slug.current != $slug && count(tags in ^.tags) > 0]
}
```

What I would translate my query to is: *"I want to get related posts  which have a different slug and that own at least one tag also owned by the current post"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count trick should work, but since you are comparing multiple tags against multiple tags, you need to iterate over them:

```
count(tags[@ in ^.^.tags]) > 0
```

In other words, it filters the tags by whether each tag appears in the other list. The additional `^.` should be needed here, as the filter introduces a new scope.

Comment: Incredible this works! Thank you so much! I should practice more of GROQ queries

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I needed! I'm getting better at GROQ but some complexe queries are tricky. I feel like writing Erlang.